# Cannot connect to WCF Web Service Reference in DotNet Core 3.1

Tags: wcf, .net-core

There is an issue for connecting to my WCF service from dotnet core 3.1 . For adding service reference I'm using `Add Connected Service` and then enters WCF URI `http://10.10.10.10:8330/mywcfservice`. If I enter the remote address as I said before it works fine and server asks for authenticate my request. but after I entered my credentials, in status box it said:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at '10.10.10.10/mywcfservice'. The remote server returned an error:(400) Bad Requst.

If I add `/` after WCF URI, in status box it said:

> An error occurred while attempting to find services at '10.10.10.10/mywcfservice/'. The remote server returned an error:(401) Unauthorized.

I tested my WCF Service with WCF Storm and it works just fine. On the other hand I can connect to WCF Service from .Net Standard Project like a charm. So where is the problem?

Comment: Hi,has the problem been solved?

Comment: hey @Dingpeng, I'm on it!

Comment: Do you have any other questions?

Comment: Not for now, let me check your solution ;)

Comment: Ok, please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: ty @Dingpeng very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I cannot know what happened to your server. You can refer to this link to record the error that occurred on the server-side:

[Trying to add a service reference results in Bad Request (400) in one project, otherwise runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23067794/trying-to-add-a-service-reference-results-in-bad-request-400-in-one-project-o)

**Another solution is to use dotnet-svcutil command:**

[image]

Use a browser to access the WSDL file of the service, and then save it locally.

[image]

Then use the dotnet-svcutil command to generate the proxy class.

[image]

Finally, add the proxy class to the project.

To use the proxy class also need to add these two packages:

[image]

Call WCF service in core:

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new  BasicHttpBinding();
 EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/GettingStarted/CalculatorService");
 CalculatorClient calculatorClient = new CalculatorClient(binding,endpointAddress);
```

**Another thing to note is that there are some WCF functions that are not supported in core. For details, please refer to the link below:**

[WCF service works in MVC client but not in .Net Core 3 client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301822/wcf-service-works-in-mvc-client-but-not-in-net-core-3-client/63333114#63333114)

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Without a doubt, this answer is so clear and straightforward that does not need any clarification (y) Thank You Ding peng